# DRF: can you deserialize one JSON key:value pair into multiple fields

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

In my API I have a module, which collects JSON objects obtained via POST request. JSON objects I'm receiving look more or less like this:

```
{
    "id": "bec7426d-c5c3-4341-9df2-a0b2c54ab8da",
    "data": {
        "temperature": -2.4,
        // some other stuff is here as well ...
    }
}
```

The problem is requirement that I have to save both: records from `data` dictionary and whole `data` dictionary as a JSONField. My ORM model looks like this:

```
class Report(BaseModel):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    data = JSONField(verbose_name=_("Data"), encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, blank=True, null=True)
    temperature = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3,
        decimal_places=1,
    )
    # other properties
```

**Is there any neat way to get both properties in one attempt to deserialize JSON object?** Currently I use nested serializers formed like this:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    temperature = serializers.DecimalField(
        source="temperature", write_only=True, max_digits=3, decimal_places=1
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ("temperature")

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source="uuid", read_only=True)
    data = DataSerializer(source="*")

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ("id", "data")
```

which obviously does not pass whole `data` dictionary to `validated_data`, which means I have to update the JSON field elsewhere (not good since I would like to have both `data` and `temperature` at `null=False` in ORM model). Any good ideas on how to fix this using DRF serializers would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be able to override `validate` method for your serializer where you can "store initial data JSON field" and do the default validation by calling `super()...` method.

More info https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

Also, there are object-level validation functions available, you can take a look there as well for the initial posted data

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation

Also, you can override the method `run_validation` to access the initially passed data object.

Comment: Serializers don't have a `clean_data` method (perhaps you meant Django forms). Also object level validations need an incoming data, in this case which doesn't exist.

Comment: Of course, it was a misspelling. `validate` method is the correct one

Comment: Even then, the answer is plain wrong. Look at the second part of my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. I tried to figure out the best way using the `run_validation` method, but eventually I've chosen to just duplicate the data JSON object in the view - which is not great, but also not terrible. Certainly better than customizing whole Serializers or smth like this. I will try to refactor it later tho.